# ¿Por qué una mala idea es una idea "descabellada"?

Tags: historia, adjetivos, locuciones

A Una mala idea o algo sin sentido lo nombramos comunmente como algo "descabellado". El DLE explica su significado:

> [**descabellado, da**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CZo4FB6)
>
> Del part. de *descabellar.*
>
> 1. adj. Que va fuera de orden, concierto o razón.

Allí se menciona que el término viene del participio de un verbo en desuso "descabellar:"

> [**descabellar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CZtcAjt)
>
> De *des*- y *cabello*.
>
> 2. tr. desus. Despeinar, desgreñar. Era u. m. c. prnl.

En la página [Significado y Origen de Expresiones Famosas](https://sigificadoyorigen.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/una-idea-descabellada/) encontré una posible explicación:

> **Una idea descabellada**
>
> En la práctica discursiva de la población se desacredita un proyecto o una propuesta con esta frase. Al decir descabellada refiriéndose a una idea, algo inmaterial, cuesta componer la figura mental de algo así como un pensamiento calvo. El tema es que descabellada significa no tener pelos y como los cabellos están sujetos al cuero que cubre el cráneo, decir descabellado es como decir que no tiene cabeza, por eso las ideas descabelladas proviene de personas sin cerebro.

Mi problema con dicha explicación es que dice: "descabellada significa no tener pelos". Eso no es lo que dice el DLE. Además, el razonamiento que siguen para concluir que descabellado es como no tener cabeza no me termina de convencer.

Ahora, si parto de la definición para "descabellar" en el DLE tendría que pensar en una idea despeinada o desgreñada, lo cual también se entiende metafóricamente, pero me hace preguntar si hay otra explicación más literal, o si hay alguna asociación que me estoy perdiendo ¿Es correcta la explicación de la página que referencio o hay algun otro origen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resulta curioso que en el diccionario de Covarrubias de 1611, la palabra *descabellado* signifique simplemente "el que trae el cabello rebuelto [sic] y desgreñado". Y ya en el *Diccionario de Autoridades*, tomo D-F (1732), se diga:

> DESCABELLADO, DA. adj. Desgreñado. Desmelenado.
>   DESCABELLADO. Se toma tambien por lo que vá fuera de orden, concierto y razón.
>   DESCABELLADO. Vale tambien desproporcionado, por mui grande ò vehemente: y se toma con freqüéncia por los últimos y mui fuertes dolóres que padecen las mugéres en el parto.

En algún momento entre estos dos puntos debió de producirse el cambio. Veamos si encontramos algo en el CORDE. Si limitamos la búsqueda a textos hasta 1600 (la época de Covarrubias), encontramos:

> *... et con las sus vnnas se rascaua et se despedaçaua los sus muyt tiernos labros, et descabellada se messaua fuertment et se arrancaua los cabellos de la carne.* (1376-1396)
>
> *... vestidas de duelo, las caras rompidas, coronas d'esparto e sogas çeñidas, 
>   descalças e rotas e descabelladas, e tristes, amargas e desconsoladas...* (a 1435)
>
> *... vieron venir a una muger desnuda y descabellada, corriendo, dando bozes...* (a 1504)
>
> *... veo a las dueñas y donzellas todas descabelladas, con las caras llenas de sangre...* (1511)
>
> *Aunque sea deshonrada en la tierra, descabellada, desnuda y afeada, aquél por cuyo amor yo sufro esto, tomará de ti venganza, enemigo de justicia, y te dará tu merecido.* (1583)

Lo primero es que me resulta curioso que prácticamente todos los casos se refieran a mujeres. Lo segundo es que, si bien es cierto que la palabra se usaba literalmente como sinónimo de *desgreñada* o *despeinada*, los ejemplos son bastante gráficos en cuanto al motivo del *despeine*. Una mujer *descabellada* no lo estaba por voluntad propia, sino por haber sido objeto de algún sufrimiento. De ahí que a partir de 1600 se comiencen a encontrar textos con la palabra como sinónimo de *dolores fuertes*, como indica el *Diccionario de Autoridades*:

> *... pues sin considerar que estoy en lo más descabellado de los dolores, no digo del aprieto de mis deudas, sino del parto de mis esperanzas...* (1613-1626)
>
> *¿En las buenas nuevas risas y risa en los dolores descabellados?* (1633)

La causa está clara: sufres unos dolores tan fuertes que te retuerces y acabas con el pelo revuelto. El cambio hacia el sentido que nos ocupa lo puedes ver en frases como la siguiente:

> *... en espeçial cantidad de mugeres corriendo descabelladas y gritando, como suçede en lugares que se saquean...* (c 1618)

Al correr como locas, las mujeres del texto se despeinaban, y ese *despeine* quedaba como sinónimo de algo que se hace sin orden ni concierto. Y ese cambio que ahora podemos comprender como una evolución lógica no tardó en llegar:

> *Su descabellado enredo / en dubias inundaciones, / si hace al oro que se anegue, / hace al carmín que se ahogue.* (a 1659)
>
> *Mayor era sin comparación su buena industria, en meter paces entre algunos indios que andaban en guerras, cuanto eran más descabelladas las razones en que se fundaban, que á no tenerlos bien conocidos, fuera imposible meterlos en camino.* (1676)

Answer (score 1):

The first definition of *descabellar* in the DLE

> 1. tr. Taurom. Matar instantáneamente al toro, hiriéndolo en la cerviz con la punta de la espada o con la puntilla.

This concept of severing the head from the spinal column seems to me to correspond to the meaning of *Que va fuera de orden, concierto o razón* mentioned in the question. After all if you have just lost the connection between your brain and the rest of your body ...

Comment: It seems so, but that definition of _descabellar_ was not present in the first DLE from the first half of the 18th century. But the _fuera de orden, concierto o razón_ definition was indeed. Besides, I can't find exampes of _descabellar_ related to bullfighting in the CORDE from that period of time or before.

Answer (score 1):

Especulación, sin fundamento que lo soporte. ¿Podría tener relación con que una mala idea haría que la gente se arrepintiera, **mesándose las barbas**, y **tirándose del pelo** (y así, quedando el pelo sin orden ni concierto?