# ¿Cuáles son las posibles etimologías de "greña"?

Tags: etimología, sustantivos

En la pregunta *[¿Por qué una mala idea es una idea "descabellada"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23144/12637)* vimos la palabra *desgreñar*, que según el DLE significa:

> **[desgreñar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=D2C7BXo)**
>
> De *des-* y *greña*.
>
> 1. tr. Descomponer, desordenar los cabellos. U. t. c. prnl.

A su vez, tenemos:

> **[greña](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JWeW9dC)**
>
> Etim. disc.
>
> 1. f. Cabellera revuelta y mal compuesta. U. m. en pl.

De aquí surgen además otras palabras como *greñudo* ("que tiene greñas"). Sin embargo, me resulta curioso que la palabra esté marcada como "de etimología discutida". ¿Es posible conocer cuáles son esas etimologías que se están debatiendo?

El *[Diccionario etimológico español en línea](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?gren.a)* comenta lo siguiente:

> ... parece tener un origen celta y estar emparentado con *grend* (barba, en irlandés antiguo), *greann* (barba en irlandés), *grön* (bigote en nórdico) y *grenon* (barba en francés antiguo).

¿Es esta la teoría que se baraja en la RAE? ¿Se pueden conocer más detalles sobre la misma, o qué razones se argumentan para apoyarla? ¿Hay alguna otra teoría sobre su origen que se esté debatiendo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Corominas, en su "Diccionario Etimológico" le dedica al tema 2 páginas. No sigo bien sus razonamientos, pero tras indicar que **GREÑA**, palabra  emparentada  con  el  **radical céltico  GRENN** 'pelo  en  la  cara'  que  permiten  suponer  las  lenguas  célticas  insulares,  pero  como  hay dificultades  fonéticas  y  el  cast.  greña  y  el  port. grenha no  se  documentan antes del S. XVI,  es  probable que deban considerarse estas  formas  romances como derivados  retrógrados  del  cast.  ant.  greñón, griñón,  port.  ant.  grenhon,  granhon,  grinhon  'cabello',  'barba',  los  cuales  representan  un celto-Íatino *GRENNIO,  -ONIS,  derivado  del  citado  radical  céltico."

Más adelante contrasta lo tardío de la primera aparición en castellano de **greña** frente a la mayor antigüedad de **greñón** y **griñón**, y analiza un posible étimo *GRENNOS (con "e" breve) para concluir que no es posible un paso directo de *GRENNOS a **greña** y concluye (o al menos, a mi me lo parece), que en las lenguas romances "...solo permiten  postular una  **base  *GRENNO,  -ONIS  (galorrománica)**,  o ***GRENNIO,  -ONIS (iberorrománica)**."

Es decir, que tenemos como posibilidades

- el radical céltico GRENN,
- la base galorrománica *GRENNO
- o la base iberorrománica *GRENNIO.

Comment: ¡Gran respuesta! ¡Bienvenido al sitio!